# Random Forests with correlated features

Tags: correlation, random-forest, feature-selection

In my dataset, I have 2 features that are not only correlated but that makes sense only in the presence of each other. For instance, one would be the number of times a task was attempted and the other one would be the number of successes.

As mentioned, it seems to be me that taken one of the 2 individually does not give any information. Should I do a scheme where if I pick one of them in a tree of my RF, I automatically include the other one?

And if so, is it possible to do so using the RF class from scikit-learn?

Thanks!

Comment: Consider asking the question on https://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You could divide one by the other as use it as a new feature

Comment: Was asked here https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/33487/random-forests-with-complementary-features

Answer (score 1):

Introduce a new feature for the  success ratio which is `successes / attempts`. Now this possibly important concept is more available to the classifier/regressor.
The Random Forest algorithm is robust towards redundant features, so you should try to leave the original features in, it may add predictive information. Look at the feature importance scores of the trained forest to understand which features were chosen.